# Apply Curl effect to a static Image C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, gdi+

Anyone ever wrote a C# GDI+ function to curl the corner of a BITMAP. I need to be able to take a static image and apply the peel effect to it on the bottom right corner. And I need to do it with C# all my searching leads to CSS3/FLASH/SilverLight virtual book type examples. I just want to create a static image that has a curled up corner and save the file.

Any Ideas?

Ok so I made the image with photo shop so that I can show you what I am trying to achieve

I start this image

[image]

and I want to write some C# code that would yield this image 
[image]
The end result is just an image that is not animated, and does nothing. Any thoughts.

Comment: You could take a look at this: [A Page Turn Effect Using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13202/A-Page-Turn-Effect-Using-C)

Comment: I already came accross that one, I Guess I should explain better. I have one image, I need to create that same image with curl up corner, no animation, no reponse to mouse. just a static image. Thanks for replying though. Perhaps I can look at the CodeProject article and use it. Not sure though.

Comment: You say you only have one image to edit, so why are you looking at doing this in C# instead of just taking the photoshopped image you've posted here?

Comment: The image I have here is an example, The is part of a much larger project that will process thousands of images, per month and doing all of this by hand just does not seem as the right way to do it. I tried creating a PhotoShop script that does this but, that creates an extra step for the users, plus not everyone using this project will have access to PhotoShop. Sorry If I was not Clear in my original Question

Comment: Is GDI+ a hard requirement? Can't you use WPF?

Comment: Yes Unfortunately GDI+ is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some good tools to do this, such as [Fred's ImageMagick plugin script](http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/pagepeel/index.php), but here is a C# version as requested.

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public partial class ImagePeelEffect : Form
{
string WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\";
public ImagePeelEffect()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void ImagePeelEffect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picBefore.Image = Image.FromFile(WorkingDirectory + "\\before.jpg");    
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a image object containing the photograph to add page peel effect
    Image imgPhoto = Image.FromFile(WorkingDirectory + "\\before.jpg");
    int phWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
    int phHeight = imgPhoto.Height;

    //create a Bitmap the Size of the original photograph
    Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(phWidth, phHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

    //load the Bitmap into a Graphics object 
    Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);

    //create a image object containing the PagePeel
    Image imgPagePeel = new Bitmap(WorkingDirectory + "\\PagePeel.bmp");
    int ppWidth = imgPagePeel.Width;
    int ppHeight = imgPagePeel.Height;

    //Set the rendering quality for this Graphics object
    grPhoto.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    //Draws the photo Image object at original size to the graphics object.
    grPhoto.DrawImage(
        imgPhoto,                               // Photo Image object
        new Rectangle(0, 0, phWidth, phHeight), // Rectangle structure
        0,                                      // x-coordinate of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        0,                                      // y-coordinate of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        phWidth,                                // Width of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        phHeight,                               // Height of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);                    // Units of measure 


    //The first step in manipulating the PagePeel image is to replace 
    //the background color with one that is transparent (Alpha=0, R=0, G=0, B=0)
    //to do this we will use a Colormap and define ImageAttributes with a RemapTable
    ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
    ColorMap colorMap = new ColorMap();

    //My PagePeel was defined with a background of 100% Green this will
    //be the color we search for and replace with transparency
    colorMap.OldColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);
    colorMap.NewColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

    //Set the Remap Table with the old and new color map
    ColorMap[] remapTable = { colorMap };
    imageAttributes.SetRemapTable(remapTable, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);


    //For this example we will place the PagePeel in the bottom right
    //hand corner of the photograph
    int xPosOfPp = phWidth - ppWidth;
    int yPosOfPp = phHeight - ppHeight + 1;

    grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPagePeel,
        new Rectangle(xPosOfPp, yPosOfPp, ppWidth, ppHeight),  //Set the detination Position
        0,                  // x-coordinate of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        0,                  // y-coordinate of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        ppWidth,            // PagePeel Width
        ppHeight,           // PagePeel Height
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, // Unit of measurment
        imageAttributes);   //ImageAttributes Object

    //Replace the original photgraphs bitmap with the new Bitmap
    imgPhoto = bmPhoto;
    grPhoto.Dispose();

    //save new image to file system.
    imgPhoto.Save(WorkingDirectory + "\\after.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    imgPhoto.Dispose();
    imgPagePeel.Dispose();

    //Show the After image
    picAfter.Image = Image.FromFile(WorkingDirectory + "\\after.jpg");

}
```

The PagePeel.bmp:

[image]

The Before and After result:

[image]

## Update

Here's a version that uses a Transparent Page Peel overlay so you dont neet to convert the "green screen" to invisible. The advantage of this method is when the original photograph contains the colour green RGB(0,255,0) it wont be turned into transparent:

TransparentPagePeel.png:

[image]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a image object containing the photograph to add page peel effect
    Image imgPhoto = Image.FromFile(WorkingDirectory + "\\before.jpg");
    int phWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
    int phHeight = imgPhoto.Height;

    //create a Bitmap the Size of the original photograph
    Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(phWidth, phHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

    //load the Bitmap into a Graphics object 
    Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);

    //create a image object containing the PagePeel
    Image imgPagePeel = new Bitmap(WorkingDirectory + "\\transparentPagePeel.png");
    int ppWidth = imgPagePeel.Width;
    int ppHeight = imgPagePeel.Height;

    //Set the rendering quality for this Graphics object
    grPhoto.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    //Draws the photo Image object at original size to the graphics object.
    grPhoto.DrawImage(
        imgPhoto,                               // Photo Image object
        new Rectangle(0, 0, phWidth, phHeight), // Rectangle structure
        0,                                      // x-coordinate of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        0,                                      // y-coordinate of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        phWidth,                                // Width of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        phHeight,                               // Height of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);                    // Units of measure 

    //For this example we will place the PagePeel in the bottom right
    //hand corner of the photograph
    int xPosOfPp = phWidth - ppWidth;
    int yPosOfPp = phHeight - ppHeight + 1;

    grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPagePeel,
        new Rectangle(xPosOfPp, yPosOfPp, ppWidth, ppHeight),  //Set the detination Position
        0,                  // x-coordinate of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        0,                  // y-coordinate of the portion of the source image to draw. 
        ppWidth,            // PagePeel Width
        ppHeight,           // PagePeel Height
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, // Unit of measurment
        null);   //ImageAttributes Object

    //Replace the original photgraphs bitmap with the new Bitmap
    imgPhoto = bmPhoto;
    grPhoto.Dispose();

    //save new image to file system.
    imgPhoto.Save(WorkingDirectory + "\\after1.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    imgPhoto.Dispose();
    imgPagePeel.Dispose();


    picAfter.Image = Image.FromFile(WorkingDirectory + "\\after1.jpg");

}
```

Comment: It may well be good enough for the OP -- but what you have here just superimposes an image of a curled page corner over the corner of the original picture: it does not "curl it up". (Compare your "after" to the OP's.)

Comment: @AAT Adobe's SDK is magic, absolutely top notch programming. It is C++ mind you (I remember back in the day building it with Motorolas' CodeWarrior). IF the OP wants the image **morphed** he should have said so. From my understanding a transparent stamp on the top should be fine. Thanks though for your feedback.

Comment: No This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - I am pleased that your solution meets what the OP is after. From my point of view your solution looks good value for money!